# Image uploading not working when dragging and dropping into rich_text_area

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actiontext

I have a strange issue in my Rails app. There is a `form.richt_text_area` and when I drag & drop an image, nothing happens. Also in the log nothing new happens.

When I create a new test application and add a `form.richt_text_area`, when dragging and dropping an image, immediately the image is uploaded. In the log I see:

```
Started POST "/rails/active_storage/direct_uploads"
```

In the original application, when I have an upload button, then uploading an attachment just works, only in a `rich_text_area` doesn't work. It is already on local, so no CORS issue. Any idea why this is not working?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue long time before.
You have to install these libraries in your PC.

**imagemagick** and **libvips**

and also install the gem **gem image-processing**

I'm using WSL on Windows, so I had to install those libraries.
Then, I started to create my own Rails Apps with Docker, and I had to install those libraries as well.

I guess that is something regard with the new Rails version (7.0.0)

I hope this helps.